# Deciding on opencv version installed separately, except opencv that comes with ROS

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake, ros

I installed ROS on linux and opencv came ready in it. I also installed a different version of opencv. But when I call opencv libraries the version from ROS is used.
How do I compile with the new opencv version?

Comment: This may help to add to your CMakeLists.txt for your code: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) That way you can put your folder before the system folders in the search.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED:**
I installed OpenCV 4.2.0 version and add one command to CMakeLists.txt.
This command is as below:
find_package(OpenCV 4.2.0 REQUIRED)

if you want to use other opencv version like 3.2.0, you can write "find_package(OpenCV 3.2.0 REQUIRED)" in CMakeLists.